# MySQL - Find closest value from another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Having trouble resolving this problem. I have a table with many rows and columns, I'm trying to find the closest value from another but it gives me different result. I want to populate the values of table2 to table1. Please find below sample data and expected result.

I have query like this.

```
select  t1.idno, t1.startdate,  
    (
    SELECT  t2.createddate
    FROM    tmp.Table2  t2
    WHERE   t1.idno = t2.idno
            and t1.startdate <= t2.createddate
    ORDER BY DATEDIFF(  t1.startdate,  t2.createddate) LIMIT 1
    ) AS createddate
```

from    tmp.Table1  t1

result from the query

```
+--------+----------------------+-------------------+
|idno    |    startdate         | createddate       |
+--------+----------------------+-------------------+
|12345340|  2021-07-13 23:45:59 |2022-07-19 15:25:01|
|12345340|  2022-02-22 10:07:41 |2022-07-19 15:25:01|
|12345340|  2022-06-17 06:20:20 |2022-07-19 15:25:01|
|12345341|  2020-12-08 17:32:51 |2022-05-30 22:45:07|
|12345341|  2021-09-07 14:35:34 |2022-05-30 22:45:07|
+--------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Table1

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
|    idno         |     startdate     |
+-----------------+-------------------+ 
| 12345340        |2021-07-13 23:45:59|
| 12345340        |2022-02-22 10:07:41|
| 12345340        |2022-06-17 06:20:20|
| 12345341        |2020-12-08 17:32:51|
| 12345341        |2021-09-07 14:35:34|
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Table2

```
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
|    idno         |     createddate    | status    |
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
| 12345340        |2022-07-19 15:25:01 |   1       |
| 12345341        |2022-05-30 22:45:07 |   0       | 
+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Expected result

```
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+
|    idno         |     startdate     |     createddate    | status|
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------|
| 12345340        |2022-06-17 06:20:20| 2022-07-19 15:25:01|  1    |
| 12345341        |2021-09-07 14:35:34| 2022-05-30 22:45:07|  0    |
+-----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
```

OR

```
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+
|    idno         |     startdate     |   createddate      | status|
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+
| 12345340        |2021-07-13 23:45:59|                    |       |
| 12345340        |2022-02-22 10:07:41|                    |       |
| 12345340        |2022-06-17 06:20:20|2022-07-19 15:25:01 |   1   |
| 12345341        |2020-12-08 17:32:51|                    |       |
| 12345341        |2021-09-07 14:35:34|2022-05-30 22:45:07 |   0   |
+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the result of your inner query? You could fix this by using UNIQUE/DISTINCT, but I don't see why you're getting duplicates in the first place

Comment: @barrycarter, another reason is the values was populated on the oldest records of idno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Please test this:

```
select  t1.idno, MAX(t1.startdate) AS startdate,MAX(
    (
    SELECT  t2.createddate
    FROM    Table2  t2
    WHERE   t1.idno = t2.idno
            and t1.startdate <= t2.createddate
    ORDER BY DATEDIFF(  t1.startdate,  t2.createddate) LIMIT 1
    )) AS createddate, t2.status
FROM Table1 as t1 JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.idno = t2.idno
GROUP BY t1.idno,t2.status;
```

If we test the result:

[image: Click to see image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Test on large data and it's working good.

Comment: You are welcome, @Jon. I am pleased to hear that. Be well!

Comment: Do I need to create new topic or update this existing questions. the requirements is the same but with a twist on the result.

Comment: @Jon It will be much better to create a new topic for more people to answer your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
SELECT t1.idno, 
       min(t1.startdate), 
       t2.creationdate
  FROM t1
  JOIN tmp.Table2 t2
    ON t1.idno = t2.idno
   AND t1.startdate <= t2.startdate
 GROUP BY t1.idno, t2.creationdate;
```